# U-SQL DataType conversion

Tags: type-conversion, u-sql

I am having a column in my sample data which contains 1 or 0 or "null".
Due to "null" string I have declared the type of the column as string.
In next operation I am taking only 1 & 0 and doing SUM(Value) where I am getting error cannot convert from "string" to "long?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To another approach to this problem you can do something like this. I'm suggesting the column name as "amount":

@input=
SELECT 
CASE column WHEN amount THEN "0" ELSE amount END  AS Amount
FROM @extractedFields

@sum=
SELECT 
SUM(Int32.Parse(Amount))
FROM @input

By this approach the input to the sum will only have in consideration the elements with 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0):

SUM fucntion works with number type, so try something like this SUM(ToInt64(VALUE))

Answer (score 0):

You can use and inline function expression as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/u-sql-functions).  Here is a simple example:

```
@input = 
    SELECT * FROM
        ( VALUES
            ( (string)"0" ),
            ( (string)"1" ),
          ( (string)"null")
        ) AS x( yourCol );


@output =
    SELECT y
    FROM
    (
    SELECT (
           (Func<string, int?>)
           (yourString =>
               {
               int yourInt;
               return int.TryParse(yourString, out yourInt) ? (int?) yourInt : (int?) null;
               }
           )
           ) (yourCol) AS y
    FROM @input
    ) AS x
    WHERE y IS NOT NULL;

OUTPUT @output
TO "/output/output.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

My results:

[image: My results]